# Adding page numbers using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

How can I add page number to a page in a document generated using PDFBox?

Can anybody tell me how to add page numbers to a document after I merge different PDFs?  I am using the PDFBox library in Java.

This is my code  and it works well but  I need to add page number.

```
 PDFMergerUtility ut = new PDFMergerUtility();
        ut.addSource("c:\\pdf1.pdf");
        ut.addSource("c:\\pdf2.pdf");
        ut.addSource("c:\\pdf3.pdf");
        ut.mergeDocuments();
```

Comment: Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I & proper names like Java, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may want to look at the PDFBox sample [AddMessageToEachPage.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/AddMessageToEachPage.java). The central code is:

```
try (PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File(file)))
{
    PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;
    float fontSize = 36.0f;

    for( PDPage page : doc.getPages() )
    {
        PDRectangle pageSize = page.getMediaBox();
        float stringWidth = font.getStringWidth( message )*fontSize/1000f;
        // calculate to center of the page
        int rotation = page.getRotation();
        boolean rotate = rotation == 90 || rotation == 270;
        float pageWidth = rotate ? pageSize.getHeight() : pageSize.getWidth();
        float pageHeight = rotate ? pageSize.getWidth() : pageSize.getHeight();
        float centerX = rotate ? pageHeight/2f : (pageWidth - stringWidth)/2f;
        float centerY = rotate ? (pageWidth - stringWidth)/2f : pageHeight/2f;

        // append the content to the existing stream
        try (PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, AppendMode.APPEND, true, true))
        {
            contentStream.beginText();
            // set font and font size
            contentStream.setFont( font, fontSize );
            // set text color to red
            contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(255, 0, 0);
            if (rotate)
            {
                // rotate the text according to the page rotation
                contentStream.setTextMatrix(Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.PI / 2, centerX, centerY));
            }
            else
            {
                contentStream.setTextMatrix(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(centerX, centerY));
            }
            contentStream.showText(message);
            contentStream.endText();
        }
    }

    doc.save( outfile );
}
```

The 1.8.x pendant was:

```
PDDocument doc = null;
try
{
    doc = PDDocument.load( file );

    List allPages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
    PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;
    float fontSize = 36.0f;

    for( int i=0; i<allPages.size(); i++ )
    {
        PDPage page = (PDPage)allPages.get( i );
        PDRectangle pageSize = page.findMediaBox();
        float stringWidth = font.getStringWidth( message )*fontSize/1000f;
        // calculate to center of the page
        int rotation = page.findRotation(); 
        boolean rotate = rotation == 90 || rotation == 270;
        float pageWidth = rotate ? pageSize.getHeight() : pageSize.getWidth();
        float pageHeight = rotate ? pageSize.getWidth() : pageSize.getHeight();
        double centeredXPosition = rotate ? pageHeight/2f : (pageWidth - stringWidth)/2f;
        double centeredYPosition = rotate ? (pageWidth - stringWidth)/2f : pageHeight/2f;
        // append the content to the existing stream
        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, true, true,true);
        contentStream.beginText();
        // set font and font size
        contentStream.setFont( font, fontSize );
        // set text color to red
        contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(255, 0, 0);
        if (rotate)
        {
            // rotate the text according to the page rotation
            contentStream.setTextRotation(Math.PI/2, centeredXPosition, centeredYPosition);
        }
        else
        {
            contentStream.setTextTranslation(centeredXPosition, centeredYPosition);
        }
        contentStream.drawString( message );
        contentStream.endText();
        contentStream.close();
    }

    doc.save( outfile );
}
finally
{
    if( doc != null )
    {
        doc.close();
    }
}
```

Instead of the message, you can add page numbers. And instead of the center, you can use any position.

(The example can be improved, though: the **MediaBox** is the wrong choice, the **CropBox** should be used, and the page rotation handling only appears to properly handle 0° and 90°; 180° and 270° create upside-down writing.)

Answer (score 5):

It is easy, try the following code

```
public static void addPageNumbers(PDDocument document, String numberingFormat, int offset_X, int offset_Y) throws IOException {
        int page_counter = 1;
        for(PDPage page : document.getPages()){
            PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true, false);
            contentStream.beginText();
            contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.TIMES_ITALIC, 10);
            PDRectangle pageSize = page.getMediaBox();
            float x = pageSize.getLowerLeftX();
            float y = pageSize.getLowerLeftY();
            contentStream.newLineAtOffset(x+ pageSize.getWidth()-offset_X, y+offset_Y);
            String text = MessageFormat.format(numberingFormat,page_counter);
            contentStream.showText(text);
            contentStream.endText();
            contentStream.close();
            ++page_counter;
        }
    }



public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("your input pdf path");
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
        addPageNumbers(document,"Page {0}",60,18);
        document.save(new File("output pdf path"));
        document.close();
    }
```

Comment: Possible improvements: **A** You use `false` as `resetContext` parameter of your `PDPageContentStream`. In case of documents with content streams that don't end in a clean graphics state, you are likely to get unwanted results. **B** You use `getMediaBox` as page size; a better choice is `getCropBox`.