# How to add a page number to the output pdf when merging two pdfs?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am using the following code to merge two pdfs:

```
File firstPdfFile = new File("firstPdf.pdf"); 
File secondPdfFile = new File("secondPdf.pdf"); 
PDFMergerUtility merger = new PDFMergerUtility(); 
merger.addSource(firstPdfFile);     
merger.addSource(secondPdfFile); 
String pdfPath = "PdfFile.pdf"; 
OutputStream bout2 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(pdfPath)); 
merger.setDestinationStream(bout2); 
merger.mergeDocuments();    
File pdfFile = new File(pdfPath);
```

I am getting the merged pdf correctly but I want to add page number in this pdf file.

Comment: If you would do it in a second pass, look at [this answer to *Adding page numbers using PDFBox*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16585032/1729265). If you want to do it in one passe, you'll have to combine that solution with [PDFMergerUtility.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/util/PDFMergerUtility.java).

Comment: If i doing like that i am getting page number wrongly.
For ex:
If firstpdf.pdf content have 2 pages means page numbers display 1 of 2, 2 of 2 like that..
and secondpdf.pdf have 3 pages means page number again 1 0f 3, 2 of 3 , like that..

Comment: In that case use the linked example to add page numbers to the source PDFs individually and then merge the enhanced source PDFs. Not difficult either I assume.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
    File firstPdfFile = new File("firstPdf.pdf");
    File secondPdfFile = new File("firstPdf.pdf");
    PDFMergerUtility merger = new PDFMergerUtility();
    merger.addSource(firstPdfFile);
    merger.addSource(secondPdfFile);
    String pdfPath = "PdfFile.pdf";
    OutputStream bout2 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(pdfPath));
    merger.setDestinationStream(bout2);
    merger.mergeDocuments();

    PDDocument doc = null;
    try {
        URL file = new URL("file:///PdfFile.pdf");
        doc = PDDocument.load(file);

        List<?> allPages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
        PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;
        float fontSize = 36.0f;
        for (int i = 0; i < allPages.size(); i++) {
            PDPage page = (PDPage) allPages.get(i);
            PDPageContentStream footercontentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, true, true);
            footercontentStream.beginText();
            footercontentStream.setFont(font, fontSize);
            footercontentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount((PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_A4.getUpperRightX() / 2), (PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_A4.getLowerLeftY()));
            footercontentStream.drawString(String.valueOf(i + 1));
            footercontentStream.endText();
            footercontentStream.close();
        }
        doc.save("PdfFile.pdf");
    } finally {
        if (doc != null) {
            doc.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code for PDFBox 2.0

```
public class PageNumberExample {

final boolean isCompress = false;
final boolean isContextReset = true;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new PageNumberExample().addPageNumber("merged PDF path");
}

public void addPageNumber(String pdfPath) throws IOException {
    File mergePpdfFile = new File(pdfPath);
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(mergePpdfFile);
    int totalPage = document.getNumberOfPages();
    for(int i=0; i<totalPage; i++) {
        PDPage page = document.getPage(i);

        PDPageContentStream stream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, isCompress, isContextReset);

        stream.setNonStrokingColor(Color.BLACK);
        stream.beginText();
        stream.setFont(PDType1Font.COURIER, 10);
        stream.newLineAtOffset(100, 100); //Set position where you want to print page number.
        stream.showText("Page " + (i+1) + " of " + totalPage);
        stream.endText();
        stream.close();
    }
    document.save(pdfPath);
    document.close();
}
}
```