# Use PDFBox to create page numbers marked as ARTIFACT for correct accessibility

Tags: pdfbox

How can I add accessible page numbers tagged as artifacts to a PDF using PDFBox?

https://www.pdfa.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/TaggedPDFBestPracticeGuideSyntax.pdf

> Section 3.7: Artifacts The process of laying out and paginating
> content for display can lead to the introduction of additional display
> items (e.g. page numbers on each page or table borders). These items
> are not part of what ISO 32000-1 defines as “real content”; they are
> considered artifacts of layout (see
> 14.8.2.2, “Real Content and Artifacts” in ISO 32000-1). A requirement for tagged PDF is to clearly distinguish “real” content from
> artifacts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See question [16581471](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581471) second answer by [Imal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3380944) for how to add vanilla page numbers to a document using PDFBox. his code is copied below with my changes for accessibility. I added the lines

```
contentStream.beginMarkedContent(COSName.ARTIFACT)
```

and

```
contentStream.endMarkedContent()
```

A snippet of Imal's excellent code with my additions is:

```
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load("Input.pdf");
    int page_counter = 1;
    int numberOfPages = document.getNumberOfPages();
    for(PDPage page : document.getPages()){
        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true, false);
        contentStream.beginMarkedContent(COSName.ARTIFACT);
        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.TIMES_ITALIC, 10);
        PDRectangle pageSize = page.getMediaBox();
        float x = pageSize.getLowerLeftX();
        float y = pageSize.getLowerLeftY();
        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(x + pageSize.getWidth()- 100, y + 20);
        String text = "Page " + page_counter + " of " + numberOfPages;
        contentStream.showText(text);
        contentStream.endText();
        contentStream.endMarkedContent();
        contentStream.close();
        ++page_counter;
    }
    document.save("Output.pdf");
```

As far as we can tell the page numbers are not in the Acrobat Pro accessibility tree, which seems correct. The page numbers seem to have been marked as artifacts.